# XML Nodes to be inserted with XSLT into a second Stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to insert some complete nodes with child nodes an all the attributes of these nodes from an XML file into a second XSLT Stylesheet, I want to create with the first one.

This is an example for the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
      xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
      xmlns:xslout="it's replaced to xmlns:xsl within the transformation">

    <text-german>

        <fo:block font-weight="bold" space-after.optimum="10mm">
            Ihr Coupon
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block space-after.optimum="10mm">
            <xsl:text>Guten Tag </xsl:text>
            <xslout:value-of select="givenname"/>
            <xslout:text> </xslout:text>
            <xslout:value-of select="surname" />
            <xslout:text>,</xslout:text>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block space-after.optimum="5mm">
            <xslout:text>Some text...</xslout:text>
            <xslout:value-of select="issuerLong" />
            <xslout:text>Here more text...</xslout:text>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block>
            <fo:inline font-style="italic">
                <xslout:text>Coupon: </xslout:text>
            </fo:inline>
            <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
                <xslout:value-of select="code" />
            </fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
    </text-german>

</data>
```

I want to insert all the content of the node `<text-german>` into the Output. Before, I have tried to do this with the command `<xsl:value of select="text-german"/>`, but this does only affect the content of this specific node, not the inherited child nodes with their content and thier attributes.

**How do I insert all the content of the node in my output file?**

For better understanding here the text i want to have in my output:

```
<fo:block font-weight="bold" space-after.optimum="10mm">
    Ihr Coupon
</fo:block>
<fo:block space-after.optimum="10mm">
    <xsl:text>Guten Tag </xsl:text>
    <xslout:value-of select="givenname"/>
    <xslout:text> </xslout:text>
    <xslout:value-of select="surname" />
    <xslout:text>,</xslout:text>
</fo:block>
<fo:block space-after.optimum="5mm">
    <xslout:text>Some text...</xslout:text>
    <xslout:value-of select="issuerLong" />
    <xslout:text>Here more text...</xslout:text>
</fo:block>
<fo:block>
    <fo:inline font-style="italic">
        <xslout:text>Coupon: </xslout:text>
    </fo:inline>
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
        <xslout:value-of select="code" />
    </fo:inline>
 </fo:block>
```

Comment: Can you show your complete output XML with your tried XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you need to use `xsl:copy-of`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/data/text-german">
        <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You'll likely have to adapt the above to suite your needs.